# Cannot open VMWare Tools on Windows Server 2016

Tags: esxi

I'm following some instructions and they say to open the VMWare tools on the guest OS by either Double-clicking the system tray icon or finding it in the control panel.  Double-clicking the icon just shows "About VMWare Tools" and there is no icon in the control panel.

I have navigated to `C:\Program Files\VMware\VMware Tools\` and there are quite a few executables in there, but I don't see any .cpl items.

How can I open the tools?

Here is what I get when I double-click the system tray icon:

[image]

Comment: See updated question.

Comment: So what are you attempting to do with VMWare Tools by double-clicking on it exactly?

Comment: Open it.  Like I said in the original post, I keep encountering instructions on the internet for various tasks that say "Double-click the VMware Tools icon (generally in the system tray at the end of the taskbar). Otherwise, choose Start > Settings > Control Panel, then double-click VMware Tools."

Comment: Have you tried updating VMWare Tools to a more recent version?  10.0.6 is more than a 3 years old.

Comment: The "install/upgrade VM tools" from the vsphere menu is grayed out. I'm assuming that's the newest version of the tools for my ESXi version.  Can I obtain them from somewhere else?

Comment: [Yes](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/info/slug/datacenter_cloud_infrastructure/vmware_vsphere/6_7#drivers_tools) the VMWare website.  You might want to verify the version of vSphere you are using is compatible with a newer version of the tools BEFORE you upgrade.

Comment: That's what I was worried about.